# How to handle "migration" in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm missing the clarity of how to handle SQLite database migration when the user doesn't want to update the app which includes additional columns for the updated app. How to handle the crash and the issues which occur when the user doesn't want to update the app. Any suggestions will be appreciable.

I have tried the following code which includes the Upgrading the database version though when user doesn't want to update the app.

Like the below in on upgrade method

```
       @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
         newVersion) {
       switch (oldVersion){
        case 1:
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_GITHUB + " ADD COLUMN " + 
                   NODE_ID + " TEXT ");

        case 2:
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_GITHUB + " ADD COLUMN " + 
                   PRIVATE + " TEXT ");

        case 3:
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE GITHUB_DATA ADD COLUMN repos_url 
                   text");
    }
}
```

I was successful in upgrading the SQLite database when the user has SQLite version 2 and made it as 3 by using the above on the upgrade method. But I have failed of getting the data from which the column I added (of repos_url column). The column has been added to the SQLite but I was unable to get the data though I have data from the server. Any suggestion will be appreciable. Thank you.

Edit:
Considering this situation If I'm maintaining the versioning using the server.

I have repos_url which i need to include for the new version user.This is the adapter i need to show in recyclerview.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GithubViewHolder githubViewHolder, int i) {

    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = githubArryaList.get(i);

    githubViewHolder.name.setText(hashMap.get("name"));
    githubViewHolder.fullname.setText(hashMap.get("full_name"));
    githubViewHolder.id.setText(hashMap.get("id"));
    githubViewHolder.node_id.setText(hashMap.get("node_id"));
    githubViewHolder.priv.setText(hashMap.get("private"));

    //new column
    githubViewHolder.repos_url.setText(hashMap.get("repos_url"));

}
```

And this is the sqlite method for sending the data.

```
public ArrayList getFavouritesData(){

    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_GITHUB,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do {

            HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.NAME,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.NAME)));
            hashMap.put(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.FULL_NAME,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.FULL_NAME)));
            hashMap.put(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.ID,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.ID)));
            hashMap.put(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.NODE_ID,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.NODE_ID)));
            hashMap.put(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.PRIVATE,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.PRIVATE)));
            hashMap.put(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.REPOS_URL,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteFavouriteDatabase.REPOS_URL)));


            arrayList.add(hashMap);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return arrayList;
}
```

The question is for the oldd version how to handle the new column data.The issue arise when there is no column called repos_url for the old version but I have to use the repos_url for the new user and i have to use the same method and adapter for both versions (new and old).How to handle this for both versions. Thank you

Comment: Hi, when you say "I was unable to get the data though", do you mean that you insert a new row with `repos_url` value, but when you select it is empty?

Comment: if user doesn't want to update the app, then you'll have to maintain a separate API/app version for their app. sqlite doesn't support your usecase.

Comment: @PozzoApps I have got the value of repos_url from the server at the same time I have updated the SQLite table column using above on upgrade method. the table has been added but the value of the repos_url is null when I checked from SQLite.db file

Comment: @kkarakk yes you are correct i got the same idea of maintining the versioning of apis but how to maintain the sqlite columns.I have added the sqlite column in sqlite db already.Will it not be a problem for the user who dont upgrade the app.We use the methods of sending data to getData() which i have added the new column (repos_url).

Comment: so it sounds like your issue is not with the table upgrade, but with the insertion or even with the data you are trying to add. Your sample code seems fine for me.

Comment: @PozzoApps yeah the issue is not with upgrading. How to sync the data for both upgraded and non-upgraded users when the additional column has been added?

Comment: ok, in that case you need to accept that old app versions wont have the new column.

Comment: @PozzoApps yeah I will accept the old app version without having the column but the problem comes like just think this way. I have added a new column for the new version so I need to use the added column value in the method where I need to send the data. But when I add the particular column to the new version the same data I am sending to the old version app where this new repos_url column value has. At the time how to handle where we are not using the value of repos_url for old app version. Or can you tell where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That is backward compatibility -- your new server is not compatible with old version of app.

While it is impossible (or difficult) to modify old version of app, you can make change in both new version of app and new version of server to handle this:

1. in new version of app, when request raised to server, add extra information to indicate this is from new version of app
2. in new version of server, when receive request from app, check if extra information is available
3. if extra information is available, it is from new version of app, you can add new columns in the response
4. if extra information is not available, it is from old version of app, you should remove new column in the response
5. new version of app will receive new columns and handle
6. old version of app will receive response without new column, and is able to handle.

Comment: Yeah you explained it in very nice way.That's awesome but i just need a clarity in one situation.I am sending the data using recyclerview which has new value called repos_url in adapter for new verison what happens when user has old version but still i am using this repos_url in adapter for both versions. @Aimin

Comment: Do you get what I mean in step 4? Server should not include repos_url in the response to old versions. Else it depends on how nice you write your old version of app -- if unknown column is just ignored, your app still survives, else it will crash.

Comment: "Server should not include repos_url in the response to old versions".....yeah but isn't it an issue when I'm including this variable in an adapter which I use for both version like I edited my question. I have to add repos_url value for the new version. But the same adapter I am using for both versions. At this point of time, what happens for old version asking for repos_url value through its having from the server for old version api.